# Determine the extremum if any of $f(x,y) = 2x^4 - 3x^2y + y^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima

My work.
$$f(x,y) = 2x^4 - 3x^2y + y^2.$$ We differentiate partially and find $$f_x = 0$$ and $$f_y=0,$$ which is indeed $0$ at $(0,0)$. Now $f_{xx} = 0$, $f_{yy}=2$ and $f_{xy}=0$. Since $f_{xx}*f_{yy} - f^2_{xy} = 0$, this requires a further probe.
So I calculated $d^2f = h^2f_{xx} + 2hkf_{xy} + k^2f_{yy} = 2k^2 $ which keeps the same sign for all values of $(h,k) \neq (0,0)$. But in the solution it says $(0,0)$ is neither a maxima nor minima as $f(x,y)-f(0,0)$ doesn't keep the same sign at the origin. My doubt is the even though necessary and sufficient conditions for the extremum are fulfilled then why can't we say the function has extremum. I have a conflict in the definition that $f(x,y)$ has to keep same sign near the extremum. Can anyone help where I am going wrong in the process. P.S. The book says the following.

> $f(a,b)$ is extreme value of $f(x,y)$ if at $(a,b)$, $df = 0$ and $d^2f$ keeps the same sign for all values of $(h,k) \neq (0,0)$.

Comment: Alternatively, if you write $f(x,y) = \left(x^2\sqrt{2} -\frac{3 y}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)^2-\frac{y^2}{8}$ and let $y = 0$, you can see that $f(x,y) = 2x^4\geq 0$ and if you let $x^2 = \frac{3 y}{2 \sqrt{2}}$, you have $f(x,y) = -\frac{y^2}8\leq 0$, so along the line $y = 0$, $f$ obtains minimum at $(0,0)$, and along the curve $x^2 = \frac{3 y}{2 \sqrt{2}}$, $f$ obtains maximum at $(0,0)$, so it is not extremum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When they say "keep the same sign" it means strictly positive or strictly negative. In your case, if you choose $h=1, k=0$ for example, you have $d^2f(1,0)=0$ so more information is needed to draw a conclusion. The condition $(h,k)\neq (0,0)$ means not both $h$ and $k$ is equal to zero (the vector $(h,k)$ is not the null vector).

To understand what happens at $(0,0)$, notice that
$$
f(x,y)=(x^2-y)(2x^2-y).
$$
Therefore, in the region where $x^2<y<2x^2$, which contains points arbitrarily close to the origin, you have $f(x,y)<0$. On the other hand, along the $X$-axis $y=0$, $x\neq 0$, you have $f(x,0)=2x^4>0$. Therefore your point is neither a local maximum or a local minimum.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(x^2-y)(2x^2-y)?$

Comment: Can you suggest some algorithmic method to approach those doubtful cases where $d^2f = 0$ as it is not always possible to factorize the expression. @GReyes

Comment: @RezaRajaei Sure. I corrected it. Thank you!

Comment: @i-don't-know There is no general recipe. One typically tries to find two different curves entering the point, in your case $(0,0)$ such that $f$ has a minimum along one of them and a maximum along the other. In this example, you could have chosen a curve between $y=x^2$ and $y=2x^2$, say $y=1.5x^2$, along which $f$ is negative.